# MongoDB replication WIndows RAM issue

Tags: mongodb

I have two production servers running Windows server 2012 R2. As a primary and secondary server, they are used for a failover scenario, where the if one fails, the other will take the load.

My application is using MongoDB replication. I have 3 instances. Primary and arbiter (which i'm going to move it on a different server, this is just a temporary souliton) and a secondary node on the secondary server.

After a time, the RAM consumption is becoming very high on both servers. MongoDB takes all the available RAM usage and does not release it. I have noted this behaviour only when the MongoDB is working in a replica.

I have done some research, and found out that it is not possible to limit the RAM usage of the mongod process itself. I'm little sceptic with MongoDB using all the RAM.

Please share your experiences, thoughts or ideas how to limit the RAM usage of the mongodb process on my windows server.

```
  rs.status()"set": "XXXXXX",
"date": ISODate("2015-03-03T13:35:39.000Z"),
"myState": 1,
"members": [
    {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "Server1:3000",
    "health": 1,
    "state": 1,
    "stateStr": "PRIMARY",
    "uptime": 67557,
    "optime": Timestamp(1425389739,
    19),
    "optimeDate": ISODate("2015-03-03T13:35:39.000Z"),
    "electionTime": Timestamp(1425322202,
    1),
    "electionDate": ISODate("2015-03-02T18:50:02.000Z"),
    "self": true
    },
    {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "Abritrer1:3001",
    "health": 1,
    "state": 7,
    "stateStr": "ARBITER",
    "uptime": 67547,
    "lastHeartbeat": ISODate("2015-03-03T13:35:38.000Z"),
    "lastHeartbeatRecv": ISODate("2015-03-03T13:35:39.000Z"),
    "pingMs": 0
    },
    {
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "Server2:3000",
    "health": 1,
    "state": 2,
    "stateStr": "SECONDARY",
    "uptime": 67542,
    "optime": Timestamp(1425389737,
    26),
    "optimeDate": ISODate("2015-03-03T13:35:37.000Z"),
    "lastHeartbeat": ISODate("2015-03-03T13:35:37.000Z"),
    "lastHeartbeatRecv": ISODate("2015-03-03T13:35:38.000Z"),
    "pingMs": 1,
    "syncingTo": "Server1:3000"
    }
],
"ok": 1
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into where the memory is going? Can you post the `mem` subdocument of `db.serverStatus()`? Also, is there anything in the logs relating to performance? Logged slow queries or long flush times?

Comment: Hello @wdberkeley. Here is the mem part of db.serverStatus()

`"mem" : {
        "bits" : 64,
        "resident" : 956,
        "virtual" : 91003,
        "supported" : true,
        "mapped" : 45402,
        "mappedWithJournal" : 90804`

No, i could not find anything in the logs regarding to performance or logged slow queries and flush time..

Answer (score 2):

We moved from using MongoDB on a production environment for this very reason.
It's not easy to force Mongo to relinquish memory, and restricting Mongo itself to a certain memory limit is similarly awkward.

If you are using Windows Server 2012, you can install the Windows System Resource Manager which should allow you to fix the maximum working set size for the Mongo process, although I have not tried this myself.

You might find the following blog post useful regarding limiting a process to a particular size.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/clinth/archive/2012/10/11/can-a-process-be-limited-on-how-much-physical-memory-it-uses.aspx

Unless you are on a Windows Server machine, I'm not sure what other tools you could use to make the change, but the approach of limiting the maximum working set allocated by the OS seems to be the best method.

Good luck!

Edit - As a thought, the Mongo memory usage will always appear high if you have a lot of data in your collections, however this does not always mean that the memory is used.
In a similar way to how Java and C# assign memory for garbage collection, Mongo marks the less recently used pages as reclaimable.
If another process requests memory, Mongo *should* release some of it's less used pages to provide the space.
It's somewhat worrying when you see that well over 3Gb of system memory is occupied by Mongo, but it isn't always as much of a problem as it seems.

As a test, you could try starting up a memory hungry application when the Mongo usage reaches its peak, and see if it releases some memory.
If it is, you might be able to simply let Mongo handle the memory usage as it sees fit (although in your position, I would rather see exactly what is free memory and what isn't).

The section on Memory Mapped Files in the Mongo FAQ sheds a little light on it.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/

Comment: Thank you Alex. Unfortunately Resource manager for WIndows Server 2012 r2 has been deprecated: technet.microsoft.com/library/hh831568.aspx I'm afraid if i let mongoDB take all the memory the server will become irresponsible (happened 2 times) I'm considering moving the replica sets to a linux (Ubuntu) machines, since mongodb is more "native" with Linux.

Comment: Moving to an Ubuntu system is certainly an option. I found that Mongo on Windows occasionally became unresponsive when we were writing data to it. Having said that, we were putting it under intense load on a very regular basis, which just proved impossible to maintain. 

It's certainly worth experimenting with the memory allocation on Linux, although I would possibly suggest using Debian as the OS due to it being somewhat lighter than Ubuntu, and frequently more stable (if not as up to date).

Comment: The test should provide reliable results. However, I'm talking about a production environment that cannot afford any downtime. As mentioned, a late reaction to our Zabbix alert that the memory consumption is above 20% free, the server became irresponsible and resulted in customer dissatisfaction and downtime.

Comment: Ah, ok, on a production environment that is pretty serious. Apologies, I missed that the server had become unresponsive twice before.
As Resource Manager is deprecated, I'm not certain what you could use to achieve the same result. There is a tool here - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/685826/Set-process-memory-limit-with-Process-Governor - which will do the same job, but it's an open source one, and I've never tried it. It could be a way to solve the issue, but I would be careful using it in a production system. It could be worth a look though. Could be a real gem of a tool.

Comment: I'm also not certain if ProcessGovenor will work with none .NET applications, but it seems to operate on the Windows process object rather than one specific to .NET, so it might do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look and try to replicate the situation and try the tool on the test environment. :)